# App is having trouble with Google Play services, please try again in ExpoKit project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have updated ExpoKit SDK from 32 to 33 version, and I changed map from expo map to react-native-maps, I did all steps for setting up react-native-maps, however, I'm still don't see map in the app, all I see is an error message:

> App is having trouble with Google Play services, please try again.

`react-native-maps version` is `0.24.0`.

How to fix this problem?

here is my app build.gradle:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'devicefarm'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28

  splits {
    abi {
      reset()
      enable true
      universalApk false
      include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.myproject'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 29
    versionName '1.1.1'
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
      def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
      def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
      if (abi != null) {
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
      }
    }
  }

  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
  }

  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
    release {
      if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
      }
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
  }

}


devicefarm {
  projectName System.getenv("DEVICEFARM_PROJECT_NAME")
  devicePool System.getenv("DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_POOL")
  executionTimeoutMinutes 40
  authentication {
    accessKey System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    secretKey System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
  }
}

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109'
  }
}

// WHEN_PREPARING_SHELL_REMOVE_FROM_HERE

apply from: 'expo.gradle'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy"

// WHEN_PREPARING_SHELL_REMOVE_TO_HERE

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
      transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker-android')
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
  implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
  implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
  implementation('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.0') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

  // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2'

  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
 // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  implementation 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0'
  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
  implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
  implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.17.1'
  implementation('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1'

  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.6.1'

  // expo-file-system
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'

  // Testing
  //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'

  implementation('host.exp.exponent:expoview:33.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp-urlconnection'
  }


  addUnimodulesDependencies([
          modulesPaths : [
                  '../../node_modules'
          ],
          configuration: 'api',
          target       : 'react-native',
          exclude      : [
                  'expo-av',
                  'expo-gl',
                  'expo-barcode-scanner',
                  'expo-mail-composers',
                  'expo-media-library',
                  'expo-sharing',
                  'expo-web-browser',
                  'expo-barcode-scanner-interface',
          ]
  ])


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-service
```

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ Please refer

Comment: I saw that guide, I did everything from that guide as well, however, I still have an error